# how to solve the equation A=s/r for s, for r?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The ratio S/R radians is independent of the radius chosen, it is only dependent on the angle A. So, we can write the following equation: A=S/R,

How do I solve it for R, for S?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this equation for the arc length $S$, simply multiply through by $R$:

1. We are given:  $A = \frac{S}{R}$
2. Next, multiply through by the radius: $AR = (\frac{S}{R})R$
3. $AR = S$, and we have solved this equation in terms of $S$.

You follow a similar process to solve for $R$.  My advice is to review how to manipulate algebraic expressions.